# How to preserve/analyse comments with x/tools/go/analysis

Tags: go

I'm currently implementing a customer linter with the go/analysis framework. Analysis is started with the multichecker:

```
multichecker.Main(
    my.Analyzer,
    my2.Analyzer,
)
```

In the resulting AST comments are not preserved. Is there an option to do this? Didn't see anything in the Analyzer struct or the Main() function that is called that hints into that direction.